# Отправка/валидация форм в Tilda в зависимости от результата работы пользовательского скрипта

Tags: javascript, tilda

В документации к Tilda нашёл способ, как отправить данные формы на свой адрес после сохранения их в Tilda. Но как сделать наоборот? Мне необходимо сначала отправить данные формы на свой адрес, и в зависимости от ответа (успех/неудача) сохранить форму в Tilda или сообщить об ошибке.